# google map with leaflet works only with 2 references to angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, leaflet

I'm trying to get a google map element on my web page and I have a really weird issue.

my dependencies:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendor/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">

<script src="/scripts/common_script.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendor/leaflet/leaflet.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendor/geosearch/css/l.geosearch.css"/>

<script src="/vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/leaflet/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/leaflet-google/leaflet-google.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/geosearch/js/l.control.geosearch.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/geosearch/js/l.geosearch.provider.google.js"></script>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false&language={{ $google_maps }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/maps.css"/>
```

The map works only if I use **2 dependencies of angularjs** (as you can see above).
If I delete one of them the map won't work anymore.

Do I miss something? is there a collision that I can't see?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean saying "won't work". Can you please check if both of that angularjs files are about the same angular.js version?

Comment: as you can see is exactly the same line:
<script src="/vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>

I've tried a lot of combination. I'm not sure if it happens because I need to load angular before\after loading of another dependency or maybe it happens because 2 times just magically fix another issue.

Comment: No, I'm asking about actual AngularJS section. You open both files and see the information at the top somethig like that: /*
 AngularJS v1.2.6
 (c) 2010-2014 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
 License: MIT
*/

So you need to compare, probably they are not identical what causes the problem and fix the same time. The important info is here: 1.2.6

Comment: /*
 AngularJS v1.2.10
 (c) 2010-2014 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
 License: MIT
*/
both

Comment: Okay, now please tell what's wrong. Do you have any exceptions? Or code stops working?